# how to fix this function its allways return false

Tags: java, sql, jsp, jdbc

I wrote this function for checking id where name is given in database but it always returns `false`:

```
public boolean checking(String name,String Id_number,String tableName){
    if(conn==null){
        System.out.println("db is not connect,is gonna connect");
        connect();
    }
    try{
        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from "+tableName+" where name ="+"'"+name+"'");
        if(Id_number.equals(rs.getString(4))){
            return true;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

How I can fix this

Comment: Are you getting a "java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set"?

Comment: no ı am not getting

Comment: I think you are, because you never call `next()` on the result set, and that will throw an exception on any correctly implemented JDBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

When a `ResultSet` is created, it points to the "before-first" row of the result. You need to attempt to advance it to the first row (using `next()`), and then compare its content. If there is no such row, you can return `false`:

```
public boolean checking(String name, String id_number, String tableName){
    if (conn==null) {
        connect();
    }

    try{ 
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        // Side note: Depending on where the parameters come from, this may be vulnarable
        // to an SQL Injection attack.
        // Make sure you properly validate/sanitize the arguments
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from " + tableName + " where name = " + "'"+name+"'");

        // Check if there's even such a row:
        if (!rs.next()) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check the id number
        return Id_number.equals(rs.getString(4));

    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(); // Or some proper handling...
    }
    return false;
}
```